How to delete old documents from Lucene index?
Is it possible to delete old documents by index (document serial number)? For example:
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, config);
IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(dir);
int numDocs = reader.numDocs();
if (numDocs>=100) // remove first (olds) 10 files
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    writer.tryDeleteDocument(reader, i);
writer.commit();

Will this work?
